# Specific slider gallery for website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have truble finding a specific slider gallery for my website.
Here is a pic of how my gallery should look like:
[image]

This should be like `width:100%` and go trought the whole width of the page.

Does anyone know for such a slider gallery I can donwload and add to my website?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is here:
http://www.jqueryrain.com/?4A0zDhn1

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! 
Exactly what i have been looking for!